# Executar comandos de OpenSSL PHP

Tags: php, jwt, openssl

Bom dia/Boa tarde/Boa Noite,

Estou precisando assinar um jwt e fazer o tal jws, foi me passado um comando comum em Linux echo -n "$(cat arq.txt)" | openssl dgst -sha256 -keyform pem -sign pmz.homologacao.key.pem | base64 | tr -d '=[:space:]' | tr '+/' '-_'

Como faria para fazer essa assinatura com php ?

Tentei da seguinte forma, porém o resultado do jws foi diferente no php e deu erro na hora da requisição para o end-print.

Answer (score -3):

Essa foi a minha tentativa
// Caminho para o arquivo
$arquivo = 'arq.txt';

// Carrega o conteúdo do arquivo
$conteudo = file_get_contents($arquivo);

// Carrega a chave privada
$chavePrivada = file_get_contents('pmz.homologacao.key.pem');

// Assina o conteúdo
$assinatura = '';
openssl_sign($conteudo, $assinatura, $chavePrivada, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

// Codifica a assinatura em base64 e realiza as manipulações necessárias
$assinaturaBase64 = base64_encode($assinatura);
$assinaturaBase64 = rtrim($assinaturaBase64, '=');
$assinaturaBase64 = strtr($assinaturaBase64, '+/', '-_');

// Imprime o resultado
echo $assinaturaBase64;